# Derived Table using group by

Tags: mysql, group-by

I'm trying to combine results from 2 different tables, where both have exactly the same schema and fields like this:

```
select * from 
(select query_type, count(query_type), campaign_id from table1 
UNION ALL
select query_type, count(query_type), campaign_id from table2
) derivedTable  group by query_type,campaign_id;
```

However, I'm not getting the results containing all the query_type and campaign_id.
Can someone please tell what I'm missing ?

Comment: Consider providing sample data set and with proper table definitions and also add your expected result set in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregate function must be in the same query (or subquery) where is `GROUP BY`, so:

```
select query_type, count(query_type), campaign_id
from (
    select query_type, campaign_id from table1
    UNION ALL
    select query_type, campaign_id from table2
  ) derivedTable
group by query_type,campaign_id;
```

Because your subquery uses aggregate function but is without `GROUP BY`, this subquery returns only one row:

```
select query_type, count(query_type), campaign_id from table1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT
      query_type
    , campaign_id
    , COUNT(query_type)
FROM (
            SELECT
                  query_type
                , campaign_id
            FROM table1
            UNION ALL
                  SELECT
                        query_type
                      , campaign_id
                  FROM table2
      ) derivedTable
GROUP BY
      query_type
    , campaign_id
;
```

OR this:

```
SELECT
        query_type
      , campaign_id
      , SUM(query_type)
FROM (
            SELECT
                  query_type
                , COUNT(query_type)
                , campaign_id
            FROM table1
            GROUP BY
                  query_type
                , campaign_id
            UNION ALL
                  SELECT
                        query_type
                      , COUNT(query_type)
                      , campaign_id
                  FROM table2
                  GROUP BY
                        query_type
                      , campaign_id
      ) derivedTable
GROUP BY
      query_type
    , campaign_id
;
```

The second form may be useful if the second table is remote, otherwise the first one above would be simplest.